# How extract strings from a .ui file (glade) with gettext?

Tags: application-development, pygtk, glade, translation

I'm trying to extract the strings from this file:

http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~gufw-developers/gui-ufw/gufw-13.04/view/head:/data/ui/add.ui

Which is the command for it?

This not works:

```
user@desktop:~/Desktop$ xgettext -k_ -kN_ -o messages.pot *.ui
xgettext: warning: file `add.ui' extension `ui' is unknown; will try C
add.ui:192: warning: unterminated character constant
add.ui:483: warning: unterminated character constant
add.ui:750: warning: unterminated character constant
user@desktop:~/Desktop$
```

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to tell `xgettext` that your file is a Glade file:

```
 xgettext -k_ -kN_ -L Glade -o messages.pot *.ui
```

Comment: Thanks Florian :) But that command isn't get all strings, all drop items are missing. As example: Allow|Deny|Reject|Limit drop.

Comment: Seems xgettext doesn't support Glade3 files yet. Change into the `po/` folder and run `intltool-update -p -g messages.pot`. Note that the project uses `gui-ufw.pot` instead of `messages.pot` so you may want to use that file, too.